# download stock data with R

Tags: r

I~m trying to download stock data with R with these code:

```
#load packages
library(stockPortfolio)
library(quadprog)

#get data of returns
stocks <- c(
  "SPY",
  "EFA",
  "IWM",
  "VWO",
  "LQD",
  "HYG")

returns <- getReturns(names(stocks), freq="week")
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
it's not possible to open the connection: HTTP status: '404 not found'
```

Comment: See what happens if you remove `names()` in your command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#load packages
library(stockPortfolio)
library(quadprog)

#get data of returns
stocks <- c(
  "SPY",
  "EFA",
  "IWM",
  "VWO",
  "LQD",
  "HYG")

returns <- getReturns(stocks, freq="week")

returns
Time Scale: week 

Average Return
         SPY          EFA          IWM          VWO          LQD          HYG 
0.0011957600 0.0002371890 0.0012480337 0.0005973494 0.0011942381 0.0012353135
```